# Debian - Intel® I219-V - NIC not detected

Tags: debian, network-interface, debian-installer, debian-cd

I have build a new PC today, however debian installation (10.9.0) cannot detect my onboard NIC.

My mobo: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/PRIME-H510M-E/

One LED is static red and the other LED is blinking orange once I connect the ethernet cable.

During installation debian says, that my network card was not automatically detected and lets me choose from a list of drivers, I found that e1000e should be compatible with this NIC, but when I manually select it, nothing happens, it puts me back to the manual driver selection menu.

On windows 10 the NIC works just fine.

[image]

I finished the installation without NIC card, then I downloaded the official driver from intel (e1000e) and loaded it successfully into kernel using modprobe. However my /etc/network/interfaces is still empty, only local loopback is there.

How do I know what is the name of the interfaces for the NIC or how do I know that the NIC is working after I loaded the driver ? Any commands to actually check that ?

Comment: You need to add more info. Can you confirm which kernel version is being used? Is the NIC a **Intel I219-V**? **lshw -c network** should give appropriate details.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem yesterday on a ASRock B560M-itx board.

The default e1000e module in debian 10 does not support the Intel l219-V. Intel didn't add support for this hardware until 3.8.4.

Debian 10 default install

```
~# modinfo e1000e | grep version:
version:        3.2.6-k
~# lspci -s 00:1f.6
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15fa (rev 11)
~# modinfo e1000e | grep 15FA
~#
```

Debian 10 with e1000e ver 3.8.7 installed.

```
~# lspci -s 00:1f.6
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15fa (rev 11)
~# modinfo e1000e | grep version:
version:        3.8.7-NAPI
~# modinfo e1000e | grep 15FA
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015FAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

Answer (score 1):

Debian 10 does works with Intel's I219-V network adapter.

However, avoid as much as you can from downloading a driver like you would do on Windows since this will bring you issues and headaches later because you'll be losing automatic updates and maintenance by the distribution.

So first things first, uninstall any modifications you've made for the Intel's website driver to work.

Now, if you don't have an RJ-45 to USB adapter or a WiFI dongle, you should try to use your phone tehering feature (4G to USB sharing) to download the right firmware.

Next, you'll need to enable the `non-free` repositories in `synaptic`, which stock comes on Debian.

Then reload the `synaptic`'s cache and install the `dkms`, then the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package.

Just reboot and everything should work.